# PHP - How do you append a numerically indexed array to a numerically indexed StdClass Object?

Tags: php, json, stdclass

For this project I am working on I have a couple constraints:

1. Plain HTML/CSS/JavaScript(or JS plugins)
2. Can use PHP scripts, but not for pages/views
3. Can't use a database
4. Keep it simple

I am trying to create a way to track bugs or issues using the above constraints. So I have come up with using JavaScript (with jQuery) to send post data via ajax to a php script. The script then checks to see if an `issues.json` file exists, and if not, it creates it.

If it exists or has been created then I use the `file_get_contents()` function and `json_decode()` function to turn it into a PHP array, or in this case a `StdClass Object`.

I then want to append the `$_POST` data (after sanitation, even though this is an internal tool), to the data found in the json file. Then I will re-write the json file with all the new (and old) data. Yeah, I'm pretty much using it like a ghetto database, but it fits within my constraints!

**JSON** Example

```
{
    "0": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email": "user@domain.com",
        "date": "2017-01-02",
        "issue_name": "Something",
        "issue_desc": "it's something for sure."
    }
}
```

**PHP** I have excluded the sanitation, checks and file re-writes because I am simply trying to get this piece to work first.

```
<?php
//Get the existing data.
$existing_data = file_get_contents("../json/issues.json");
$decoded = json_decode($existing_data);

//For Testing purposes
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($decoded);
echo "</pre>";

if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $_POST = (object) $_POST;

    $newData = array_merge((array)$decoded, array($_POST));

    //For Testing purposes
    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($newData);
    echo "</pre>";
}

$json = json_encode($newData);

echo $json;
```

**The result** of this transaction is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => John Doe
            [email] => user@domain.com
            [date] => 2017-01-02
            [issue_name] => Something
            [issue_desc] => it's something for sure.
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => John Doe
            [email] => john.doe@domain.net
            [date] => 2016-02-12
            [issue_title] => Problem with software
            [issue_desc] => the description of the problem
        )

)
```

I realize the issues with converting arrays to objects and vice versa, as evidenced above. However, I can't seem to get it to work like how I want.

I have tried using [ArrayObject::append()](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.append.php) :

```
$arrayobj = new ArrayObject($decoded);
$arrayobj->append($_POST);
```

And I get some weird output:

```
ArrayObject Object
(
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [name] => John Doe
            [email] => john.doe@domain.net
            [date] => 2016-02-12
            [issue_title] => Problem with software
            [issue_desc] => the description of the problem.
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => John Doe
                            [email] => user@domain.com
                            [date] => 2017-01-02
                            [issue_name] => Something
                            [issue_desc] => it's something for sure.
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I have also tried [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) (see the code) but without the object/array casting it throws an error about how the StdClass Object isn't an array (obviously). The result from using the `array_merge()` function, like how I have in the code, is the closest (so far) of what I want.

**Desired Output**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => John Doe
            [email] => user@domain.com
            [date] => 2017-01-02
            [issue_name] => Something
            [issue_desc] => it's something for sure.
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => John Doe
            [email] => john.doe@domain.net
            [date] => 2016-02-12
            [issue_title] => Problem with software
            [issue_desc] => the description of the problem
        )

)
```

I want the keys to increment, which it would do naturally (if I was doing it "right"), so I can add as much data as I want.

So, now to my question (finally): **How do you append a numerically indexed array (containing `$_POST` information) to a numerically indexed StdClass Object in PHP?**

Am I missing something? I have been at this for a full day and feel like I am missing something fundamental. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why do you intend using stdClass? What's wrong with arrays here?

Comment: Why not just use `json_decode($existing_data, true)` to get the data as an array, then just append the current one with something like `array_push($decoded, $_POST[0])`?

Comment: I knew it was something simple, it's been so long since I've used `json_decode()` I totally forgot about that second parameter. Thank you, saved my bacon. If you want to add that as the answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

Check my code, this works as requested:

```
$decoded = json_decode('{
    "0": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email": "user@domain.com",
        "date": "2017-01-02",
        "issue_name": "Something",
        "issue_desc": "it\'s something for sure."
    }
}');

$_POST = array('name' => 'test');

$merged = (object)array_merge((array)$decoded, array((object)$_POST));
print_r($merged);
```

Which gives me:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => John Doe
            [email] => user@domain.com
            [date] => 2017-01-02
            [issue_name] => Something
            [issue_desc] => it's something for sure.
        )

    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => test
        )

)
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Can you update your post with `(array)$decoded` and `array($_POST)` dumps (from print_r())?

Comment: Check my edit, at first look I did not fully understood your question. I just used two casts...

Comment: I think I figured it out. The only problem with your solution was that it wasn't incrementing the indexes. I'll post as an answer how I did it. If you see a better way, feel free to edit your answer again.

Comment: `$merged = (object)array_merge(array_values((array)$decoded), array_values(array((object)$_POST)));` ?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that all the casting and un-casting was bloating the script. So I did even more research, asked some co-workers and this is what I came up with:

```
//Get the existing data.
$existing_data = file_get_contents("../json/issues.json");
$decoded = json_decode($existing_data, true);

//Check if we're dealing with POST data
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    if(!empty($decoded)) {
        // Use array_unshift to put the newest issues at the beginning of the array, so they don't have to be sorted by date.
        array_unshift($decoded, $_POST);
    } else {
        $decoded = array();
        // Use array_unshift to put the newest issues at the beginning of the array, so they don't have to be sorted by date.
        array_unshift($decoded, $_POST);
    }
}

//Put the existing data.
$json = json_encode($decoded);
file_put_contents("../json/issues.json", $json);
```

**Explaination**
First i get the file contents of the issues.json file, and decode it to a PHP array, setting the `$assoc` parameter to true so it returns an array instead of an object per [kunruh's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368563/php-how-do-you-append-a-numerically-indexed-array-to-a-numerically-indexed-std#comment-58446514).

Then I simply check if we're getting data from `$_POST` and if we are, I check that we're getting data from `$decoded`. Since if the .json file is empty, it will cause an internal server error when trying to push array bits something to `null`. So to safeguard against that I made an empty array and just pushed to that.

After that logic, it's a simple matter re-encoding it and `put`ing the data back in the file. Works like a charm! Hope this is able to help other people.